# Why can't I display information from two models inheriting from another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So the engineer and manager model inherit from the person model, which includes the first name, last name and full name as well as the person id. The change model has lazy loading for all the details of engineers and managers and status and all that.

When I try the below code using seed data from an initializer, the engineer column and the manager column are blank. Unless I use the variable "PersonId" instead of "EngineerId" in the change model and leave out either ManagerId or EngineerId, it cannot access the person model details of that user. I need to use EngineerId because I also have the Manager which is inheriting from the same model. I need both names to show up in the index. It's like it doesn't know that EngineerId refers to the Engineer model or that ManagerId refers to the Manager model, both inheriting from Person. So when I put an Id in there during initialization, it can't seem to determine what that ID refers to. I need to use inheritance because I want a single set of users in this app. What am I doing wrong?

The thing is, also, that it has no problem displaying the StatusName and SystemName and even more weird is that in the index.cshtml it has no problem seeing that engineer is part of Person, but I guess that's because it's set that way in the Change model. There's some disconnect somewhere between the EngineerId and its associated PersonId.

Here's the change model:

```
public class Change
{
    [Key]
    public int ChangeId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Change description is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Change Description")]
    public string ChangeDescription { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Change date is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Change Date")]
    public DateTime ChangeDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Engineer name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Engineer")]
    public int EngineerId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Manager is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Manager")]
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "System is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "System")]        
    public int SystemDetailId { get; set; }

    public virtual Engineer engineer { get; set; }
    public virtual Status status { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemDetail systemdetail { get; set; }
    public virtual Manager manager { get; set; }

}
```

Here's the person model:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The First Name field is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Last Name field is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the engineer model for example:

```
public class Engineer : Person
{
    public ICollection<Manager> managers { get; set; }
}
```

This is what the index comes up with when the views are generated from creating the change controller.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.status.StatusName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.systemdetail.SystemName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ChangeDescription)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ChangeDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EngineerId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ManagerId)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status.StatusName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.systemdetail.SystemName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ChangeDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ChangeDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.engineer.FullName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.manager.FullName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ChangeId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ChangeId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ChangeId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Oh and the change controller:

```
public class ChangeController : Controller
    {
        private ChangeContext db = new ChangeContext();

        // GET: Change
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var changes = db.changes;
            return View(changes.ToList());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have pk and fk setted in your database?

Comment: @Hadee I'm new to all this mvc stuff this is my first effort to make an app after watching tutorials. The primary key you mean? It's set on all the models except the ones inheriting from Person. Maybe I should add an EngineerId and ManagerId to those two models? The problem is they use the PersonId.

Comment: So you have database and pk and fk setted? and if so do you use database first approach?

Comment: @Hadee You may have to help expand on that, like I said I'm a bit new to this. I tried seeing if in the view's index page I could find by id the person using the engineerid and display the name that way. I am still struggling to figure out the syntax or method of doing it that way.

Comment: you first set your pk and fk correctly in database. Then try to implement entity frame work database first approch. check this for details: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database. Then you shouldn't have problem to what you see now. If you have any problem or don't know how to start, say to give you details.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution without having to take a database first approach. The answer was a two fold solution because cascade errors occur if you don't follow both of these steps.

The first step is to add the "ForeignKey" annotation to the relevant controller, in this case the Change controller.

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Engineer name is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Engineer")]
        [ForeignKey("engineer")]
        public int EngineerId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Manager is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Manager")]
        [ForeignKey("manager")]
        public int ManagerId { get; set; }
```

The second step is to add the following line to your Context model:

> modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove();

As shown below in mine:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
}
```